# Define class matrix of integers using vector

Tags: c++

I have run the following code.
Errors I got are: `invalid types array subscripts`
Is there any mistake in using the constructor?
While I run it normally without using any constructor, I got an error output.
These are the errors I got, please check out what my mistake is:

`invalid types 'const int[int]' for array subscript inside the = operator`

and

`[Error]  invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript inside print function in the program.`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
   int i,j,x,y;
   vector<int> v;
   vector<int> b;

   public:
   Matrix()
   {
   }

   Matrix(int m, int n) //Main constructor
   {
       x=m;
       y=n;
       vector< vector <int> > v(x,vector <int>(y));
       cout<< "enter values into the vector" << endl;
       for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < y; ++j)
           {
               cin >> v[i][j];
           }
       }
   }

   Matrix(const Matrix &t)
   {
       x=t.x;
       y=t.y;
       v=t.v;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
       cout << "copy constructor called" << endl;
   }
   ~matrix()
   {
       cout << "destructor called" << endl;
   }

   Matrix operator=( const Matrix &r)
   {
       x=r.x;
       y=r.y;
       vector< vector <int> > b(x,vector <int>(y));
       for (i=0;i<x;++i)
       {
           for (j=0;j<y;++j)
           {
               b[i][j]=r.v[i][j];
           }
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
           {
               cout << b[i][j] << "  ";
           }
           cout << endl;
       }
   }

   void print()
   {
       for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
       {
           for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
           {
               cout << v[i][j] << "  ";
           }
           cout << endl;
       }
   }
};

int main()
{
   int d1,d2;
   cout << "enter row,column values" << endl;
   cin >> d1 >> d2;
   Matrix ob1();
   Matrix ob2(d1,d2);
   cout << "elements in the matrix using constructor are" << endl;
   ob2.print();
   Matrix ob3(ob2);
   cout << "elements in the copy constructor" << endl;
   ob3.print();
   cout << "after overloading assignment operator" << endl;
   Matrix ob4;
   ob4=ob2;
   return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance. It looks there is too much code with respect to text in this question, so needed to add a few words here.

Comment: well you are using two times the square brackets operator with a vector that contains just ints.
Maybe you want to use a `vector<vector<int>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Federico quickly spotted, class data `v` is initially defined just as a `vector<int>`, but then used throughout the member functions as `vector< vector<int> >`.
No need to define `b` and loop indices `i,j` as class data.

In addition, `v` in the assignment operator was redefined locally, so even after having correctly compiled, the program would not have yielded the desired results.

This MWE below should work as intended

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
   int x,y;                    // redundant class data erased 
   vector< vector <int> > v;

   public:
   Matrix(): x(0), y(0), v(0)
   {
   }

   Matrix(int m, int n) // Main constructor
   {
       x=m;
       y=n;
       v = vector< vector<int> >(x,vector <int>(y, 0));   // in original version, this class data was redefined locally
       cout<< "enter values into the vector" << endl;
       for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < y; ++j)
           {
               cin >> v[i][j];
           }
       }
   }

   Matrix(const Matrix &t)
   {
       x=t.x;
       y=t.y;
       v=t.v;
       cout << "copy constructor called" << endl;
   }

   ~Matrix()
   {
       cout << "destructor called" << endl;
   }

   Matrix& operator=(const Matrix &r)   // needs to output a reference
   {
       if (this == &r)   // check self-assignment
           return *this;

       x = r.x;
       y = r.y;
       vector< vector<int> > b(x,vector <int>(y, 0));
       for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < y; ++j)
           {
               b[i][j] = r.v[i][j];
           }
       }

       for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
           {
               cout << b[i][j] << "  ";
           }
           cout << endl;
       }

       return *this;
   }

   void print()
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
           {
               cout << v[i][j] << "  ";
           }
           cout << endl;
       }
   }
};

int main()
{
   int d1,d2;
   cout << "enter row, column values" << endl;
   cin >> d1 >> d2;
   Matrix ob1();
   Matrix ob2(d1,d2);
   cout << "elements in the matrix using constructor are" << endl;
   ob2.print();
   Matrix ob3(ob2);
   cout << "elements in the copy constructor" << endl;
   ob3.print();
   cout << "after overloading assignment operator" << endl;
   Matrix ob4;
   ob4=ob2;

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
enter row, column values
3 3
enter values into the vector
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
elements in the matrix using constructor are
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
copy constructor called
elements in the copy constructor
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
after overloading assignment operator
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
```